# Cannot Write Data to ElasticSearch with AbstractReactiveElasticsearchConfiguration

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, junit5, java-11, spring-reactive

I am trying out to write data to my local Elasticsearch Docker Container (7.4.2), for simplicity I used the AbstractReactiveElasticsearchConfiguration given from Spring also Overriding the entityMapper function. The I constructed my repository extending the ReactiveElasticsearchRepository
Then in the end I used my autowired repository to saveAll() my collection of elements containing the data. However Elasticsearch doesn't write any data. Also i have a REST controller which is starting my whole process returning nothing basicly, DeferredResult>

The REST method coming from my ApiDelegateImpl

```
  @Override
  public DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<Void>> openUsageExporterStartPost() {

    final DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<Void>> deferredResult = new DeferredResult<>();

    ForkJoinPool.commonPool().execute(() -> {

          try {
            openUsageExporterAdapter.startExport();
            deferredResult.setResult(ResponseEntity.accepted().build());

          } catch (Exception e) {
            deferredResult.setErrorResult(e);
          }
        }
    );

    return deferredResult;
  }
```

My Elasticsearch Configuration

```
@Configuration
public class ElasticSearchConfig extends AbstractReactiveElasticsearchConfiguration {

  @Value("${spring.data.elasticsearch.client.reactive.endpoints}")
  private String elasticSearchEndpoint;

  @Bean
  @Override
  public EntityMapper entityMapper() {

    final ElasticsearchEntityMapper entityMapper = new ElasticsearchEntityMapper(elasticsearchMappingContext(), new DefaultConversionService());
    entityMapper.setConversions(elasticsearchCustomConversions());
    return entityMapper;
  }

  @Override
  public ReactiveElasticsearchClient reactiveElasticsearchClient() {
    ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = ClientConfiguration.builder()
        .connectedTo(elasticSearchEndpoint)
        .build();

    return ReactiveRestClients.create(clientConfiguration);
  }
}
```

My Repository

```
public interface OpenUsageRepository extends ReactiveElasticsearchRepository<OpenUsage, Long> {

}
```

My DTO

```
@Data
@Document(indexName = "open_usages", type = "open_usages")
@TypeAlias("OpenUsage")
public class OpenUsage {

  @Field(name = "id")
  @Id
  private Long id;

  ......
}
```

My Adapter Implementation

```
  @Autowired
  private final OpenUsageRepository openUsageRepository;

  ...transform entity into OpenUsage...

  public void doSomething(final List<OpenUsage> openUsages){
   openUsageRepository.saveAll(openUsages)
  }
```

And finally my IT test

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@Testcontainers
@TestPropertySource(locations = {"classpath:application-it.properties"})
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = OpenUsageExporterApplicationIT.Initializer.class)
class OpenUsageExporterApplicationIT {


  @LocalServerPort
  private int port;

  private final static String STARTCALL = "http://localhost:%s/open-usage-exporter/start/";

  @Container
  private static ElasticsearchContainer container = new ElasticsearchContainer("docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.8.4").withExposedPorts(9200);

  static class Initializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(final ConfigurableApplicationContext configurableApplicationContext) {

      final List<String> pairs = new ArrayList<>();

      pairs.add("spring.data.elasticsearch.client.reactive.endpoints=" + container.getContainerIpAddress() + ":" + container.getFirstMappedPort());
      pairs.add("spring.elasticsearch.rest.uris=http://" + container.getContainerIpAddress() + ":" + container.getFirstMappedPort());
      TestPropertyValues.of(pairs).applyTo(configurableApplicationContext);
    }
  }

  @Test
  void testExportToES() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    final List<OpenUsageEntity> openUsageEntities = dbPreparator.insertTestData();
    assertTrue(openUsageEntities.size() > 0);

    final String result = executeRestCall(STARTCALL);

    // Awaitility here tells me nothing is in ElasticSearch :(

  }

  private String executeRestCall(final String urlTemplate) throws IOException {

    final String url = String.format(urlTemplate, port);

    final HttpUriRequest request = new HttpPost(url);
    final HttpResponse response = HttpClientBuilder.create().build().execute(request);

    // Get the result.
    return EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void doSomething(final List<OpenUsage> openUsages){
 openUsageRepository.saveAll(openUsages)
}
```

This lacks a semicolon at the end, so it should not compile.

But I assume this is just a typo, and there is a semicolon in reality.

Anyway, `saveAll()` returns a `Flux`. This `Flux` is just a recipe for saving your data, and it is not 'executed' until `subscribe()` is called by someone (or something like `blockLast()`). You just throw that `Flux` away, so the saving never gets executed.

How to fix this? One option is to add `.blockLast()` call:

```
openUsageRepository.saveAll(openUsages).blockLast();
```

But this will save the data in a blocking way effectively defeating the reactivity.

Another option is, *if the code you are calling `saveAll()` from supports reactivity* is just to return the `Flux` returned by `saveAll()`, but, as your `doSomething()` has `void` return type, this is doubtful.

It is not seen how your `startExport()` connects to `doSomething()` anyway. But it looks like your 'calling code' does not use any notion of reactivity, so a real solution would be to either rewrite the calling code to use reactivity (obtain a `Publisher` and `subscribe()` on it, then wait till the data arrives), or revert to using blocking API (`ElasticsearchRepository` instead of `ReactiveElasticsearchRepository`).

Comment: Yes i realized that need someone who subscribes to the channel, my initial thought was the elasticsearch would do the block() for me but i was a fool. However my thought came to conclusion that in case should i aim for reactive I need to return the response flux. Anyways thanks for the response